# Magento 2 additional image import issue with different url and same name

Tags: image, import, magento2, product

I attempted to programmatically import product additional images from third-party URLs.Working with root script.

However, the URLs are different, and the names are the same. Does anyone have an idea of how we can upload all the images as additional images?

Example
`https:/example.com/100/abc.jpg,  https:/example.com/200/abc.jpg,  https:/example.com/300/abc.jpg`

Thanks in advance.

By using root script want to upload all additional images from third party urls.